# Does hibernate locks main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, apache-mina

I'm using hibernate together with apache mina to build Multiplayer game server. I have separate client class for each (apache mina) client, separate transaction and session.
So, the question is:

> Does hibernate blocks my main thread when i'm saving my entity to database or performing huge select query?

Comment: "Blocks" and "locks" are two very different things.  Which are you asking?

Comment: I mean lock i think. I don't want to have any delay with syncing player movements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your JDBC calls are synchronous so they will block until something is returned from the database, this is not specific to Hibernate.

You could create a separate thread and handle your DB actions using that. Be warned though you will run into issues sharing entities across threads such as fetching lazy relationships.

Comment: Whoa.  Seriously, there are issue in Hibernate with sharing entities across threads?  Could point to documentation on that?

Comment: @markspace Sessions are not thread safe, though reattaching entities is not impossible. For write operations where you do not care about the result you won't have an issue. https://pveentjer.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/sharing-hibernate-entities-between-threads/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549386/modifying-hibernate-entities-from-multiple-threads